# Swift/iOS which notification mechanism is the most reliable one?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, mqtt, pushkit

We are currently devleoping an iOS application based on Swift 4. The iOS app receives some very important notifications that should arrive as fast and as reliable as possible even if the app is not active (e.g. in the backgrond).

So we are currently asking ourself which notification mechanism is best to use. We are considering the following:

- Apple Push Notifications that directly show a notification to the user
- Apple Silent Push Notifications that will create a LocalNotification
- MQTT (but I guess its not working in the background?)
- Apple PushKit for VoiP

Can you help us on this? As far as some internet research showed Apple PushKit seems to be the most reliable one. But can we use it although we do not actually have a voip feature in our app?

Thx a lot for your help.

Best,
mooonli

Comment: Apple push notifications should be pretty reliable.  Silent push notifications can't be delivered to your app if it isn't running.  PushKit will launch your app if required, but it is for VoIP applications.  MQTT won't work if your app isn't in the foreground, so I would use standard Apple Push Notifications. Be aware that no push notification system has guaranteed delivery; The user could have turned off notifications, put the device in Airplane mode, have no service etc,.

Comment: Hi Paulw
Thx for getting back to me. Is Apple Push Notification (standard) more reliable than Apple Silent Push Notifications (except the fact that silent wont work if app is completely terminated)? and could PushKit still be used although we do not have a voip feature yet?

Comment: I would expect standard push, silent push and PushKit to have basically the same level of reliability.  The difference is how they are handled when your app is in the background/not running.  Silent pushes can be rate limited if you send too many in a short period of time.

Comment: Did you consider sending a text message?

Comment: the answer depends on what you'd like to achieve...

Comment: Hi guys
The purpose of our application is that patiens (e.g. in a hospital) can communicate their needs through an ipad app. The corresponding need (e.g. they are thirsty, have some pain, ...) will be sent to an iphone app that runs on the nurse's iphone. Thats why its quite important for us that the notification is as reliable as possible because we have to make sure that it reaches the nurse as soon as possible.

Any ideas on how we can achieve this or which kind of notification is best for that?

Comment: Since our app does not need to be submitted in the appstore but will be distributed through mdm we could also use some not-apple-approved stuff if it would e.g. be possible to use MQTT and keep the connection alive also in background mode with some kind of a "hack" ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** (after some more information)

Ok, after reading about your use case, I actually think we can simplify this a lot and still have a highly reliable approach.

Assumptions:

- iPads for users are probably going to be hospital owned, and wont have any issues with not receiving notifications, cause they are senders only.
- Nurses phones in the other hand can be intentionally or unintentionally configured to receive or not notifications)
- You don't really do not perform any critical action in the app based on the notification, you just need the nurse to act on it

With this in mind my suggestion to you is to use regular push notifications and SMS notifications as a backup.

1. When user taps the ipad to say they are hungry/thirsty/in pain, your backend receives that request and fires the push notification.
2. Your backend now starts a timer for when it should expect a ping saying the notification has been read (nurse opens the app because of notification).
3. If backend doesnt get a ping in 1 min (or whatever is your threshold), your backend now fires a SMS message, which is carrier delivered.
4. If your backend still havent got a ping, you repeat steps 2 and 3 but sending to a secondary contact (head nurse?, doctor?)
5. When app gets opened, you fetch all the notifications pending and do whatever you need to do (ask nurse to confirm receipt or confirm action was taken)
6. You can even have a emergency backup that if the ping never happened in a maximum timeframe (30 min? 1 hour?), the ipad for the user shows a warning message asking user to use the physical "call a nurse" button.
7. You can invert priorities based on user requested action (SMS first for "in pain" triggers, Push for all the rest).

You can definitely trust the push service as it is very reliable, and it provides you some debug data, but just make sure you have a fallback method and a fallback of the fallback method :P

---

**Original Answer**

First you have to ask yourself why is it so important for your app to receive a notification. What do you really need to accomplish that you can't when the user opens the app.

You should never rely on notifications to perform important actions on your app, one a notification is just that, a piece of information to the user. It should never be a form of performing critical activities.
Of course you are able, with all the methods you specified, to perform actions upon receiving a notification, but it should only be actions that can help your app execute some sort of logic faster than if manually triggered.

Make sure you architect your app in a way that critical information that needs to get triggered constantly, can be executed multiple ways. So you can trigger by doing a push or a silent push, if that didn't work, user get an email to do something that will open the app and manually trigger it, etc...

Remember, these types of notifications can be manually disabled, can be enabled but failed to be delivered, as pushes are basically fire-and-forget.

I don't know what your app is about, but try to always think about the ramifications of flows like this to the user and what can happen if critical activities are not executed when they should.

Sorry if this was not helpful in terms of what you were actually looking for, but I have already been part of two major apps that "relied" on notifications for executing things, and we always had a lot of problems trying to create workarounds.

Comment: Hi gmogames
Thx for your input. I added some additional infos about our app and use case above.

Comment: Hi gmogames
Okay thanks a lot for your feedback. And is it correct, that silent APNs are less reliable or lower prioritized than standard APN's? Since one option could be to sent silent notifications, handle them and if necessary create a LocalNotification for the user within the handler of silent notification?